# For all real numbers $x$, we have $x \leq -5$ if and only if $1 \leq \frac{2x+3}{x-2} \leq 2$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the Theorem in the title. I need help verifying my solution.

---

For all real numbers $x$, we have $x \leq -5$ if and only if $1 \leq \frac{2x+3}{x-2} \leq 2$.

Proof. To prove the implication, by adding $x+3$ to both sides of $x\leq -5$, one obtains

\begin{align}
2x+3 \leq x-2
\end{align}

Since $x \leq -5$, one can divide both sides of the inequality and obtains,

\begin{align}
\frac{2x+3 }{x-2} \geq 1
\end{align}

By taking the limit of $\frac{2x+3}{x-2}$ as $x$ approaches $-\infty$,

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{2x+3}{x-2} = \lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{2+\frac{3}{x}}{1-\frac{2}{x}} = 2
\end{align}

Hence, $1 \leq \frac{2x+3}{x-2} \leq 2$.

To prove the converse, observe that if $x-2 \geq 0$, by multiplying both sides of $1 \leq \frac{2x+3}{x-2} \leq 2$ by $x-2$, one obtains

\begin{align}
x-2 \leq 2x+3 \leq 2x -4\\
-2 \leq x+3 \leq x-4\\
-5 \leq x \leq x-7
\end{align}

Since no non-negative $x$ satisfies the above inequalities, $x-2$ can not be greater than or equal to $0$.

In case that $x-2 < 0$ by multiplying both sides by $x-2$, one obtains

\begin{align}
x-2 \geq 2x+3 \geq 2x -4\\
-2 \geq x+3 \geq x-4\\
-5 \geq x \geq x-7
\end{align}

Because all $x \in (-\infty , -5]$ satisfy the above inequalities, $x-2 < 0$ and $x \leq -5$.

Since the implication and its converse are both true, $x\leq -5$ if and only if $1 \leq \frac{2x+3}{x-2} \leq 2$.

---

Comment: Your limit argument for the direct implication does not work.

Comment: @Zuy Is it because the limit of the function is not equal to 2 or the limit can not be used in this proof?

Comment: For the argument to work, you would first need to prove that $\frac{2x+3}{x-2}$ is a decreasing function (for $x<2$). Maybe you know that, in which case you proof is fine. By the way, for the converse direction, when you argue that $-5\leq x\leq x-7$ doesn't hold, it suffices to consider the right inequality; it gives that $0\leq -7$, a contradiction.

Comment: The statement should require $x\neq2$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch For most people, this is implicit: If $x\leq -5$, it is clear, and in order to write down $\frac{2x+3}{x-2}$, you silently assume $x\neq 2$.

Comment: For a more direct approach, multiply by the square of the denominator (to ensure positivity), then factorize accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

learn to draw simple graphs by hand, say by plotting a few points (either $x$ or $y$ integers, for example).  In any case the graph of a non-constant, non-linear Mobius transformation is a hyperbola  with a horizontal asymptote and a vertical asymptote.

Furthermore, it is easy to invert a Mobius transformation, and this particular one is an agreeable surprise: if  $y = \frac{2x+3}{x-2}, $ then $$x = \frac{2y+3}{y-2}.$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have $1 \leq \frac{2x+3}{x-2} \leq 2$, which is a rational inequality in two parts. First, consider the first part: we have
$$ 1\leq \frac{2x+3}{x-2}\\
\frac{2x+3}{x-2}-1 = \frac{2x+3-x+2}{x-2} = \frac {x+5}{x-2} \geq 0\text{.} $$
For this fraction to be non-negative, its numerator and denominator must share the same sign, or the numerator has to be zero. We thus have
$$(x+5\geq 0\land x-2 > 0)\implies x > 2\bigvee (x+5\leq 0\land x-2 < 0)\implies x\leq -5\text{,}$$ giving us the partial set of solutions $$A = (-\infty ;-5]\cup (2;\infty )\text{.}$$
For the second part of the inequality:
$$ \frac{2x+3}{x-2} \leq 2\\
\frac{2x+3}{x-2} - 2 = \frac{2x+3-2x+4}{x-2} = \frac{7}{x-2} \leq 0\\
\frac{1}{x-2} \leq 0\text{,} $$
clearly giving $$ B = (-\infty ;2)\text{.} $$
Combining the two intervals yields $$ x\in A\cap B = (-\infty ;-5)\iff x\leq -5\text{.} $$

Answer (score 0):

We have $x\le-5\iff x=-5-h$ where $h\ge0$ so we have
$$\frac{2x+3}{x-2}=\frac{-2h-7}{-7-h}=\frac{2h+7}{7+h}=1+\frac{h}{7+h}$$ We are done because it is evident that $1\le1+\dfrac{h}{7+h}\le2$.